# object created inside jQuery 'click' persists even though a new one is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scope, this

very new to JQuery so my code is probably not the best approach, so tips there would be nice...

But the problem is that the `reqObj` created inside the click function doesn't ever seem to be dismissed. If the function runs through and I console.log the object i get both the new one created and all the previous ones that were created as well. I tried putting the object outside the function but that doesn't work. I'm sure this is a quick fix. Thank you for any help.

P.S. the div's are created dynamically in javascript based on incoming data

```
$(document).on('click', '.profileDiv', function(){
    var outer = this;
    $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
    $('#headerModal').text('Would like to request a session with ' + $(outer).find('#pro_first_name').text());
    $(document).on('click', '#modalRequest', function(){
      var reqObj = {};
      reqObj = {
        pro_id : $(outer).attr('id'),
      }
      console.log(reqObj);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nesting events is bad practice especially if you don't unbind nested one in some way. Here, each time you click `.profileDiv`, you bind a new click event on `#modalRequest` without unbinding any previous one. And anyway, there is absolutely no reason you nest delegated event bound to `document` level. What would work for you is: `$(document).off('click','#modalRequest').on('click', '#modalRequest', function(){...});`. But like said, this is just bad practice

Comment: `$(outer).attr('id') === outer.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really bind and event inside another event callback, and as you are using event delegation you don't really need to. What you are trying to do is pass data from the callback of one event to another.

You can achieve this through using global variables that all functions have access to, however this is an anti pattern as it can change at anytime by any piece of the code.

jQuery gives you a better way however to attach metadata to elements so you can easily transfer or store the state using `jQuery.fn.data` it's much better than resorting to global variables.

```js
$.fn.modal = function(){}

$(document).on('click', '.profileDiv', function() {
  var outer = this;
  $("#myModal")
    .data('reqObj', {
      pro_id : $(outer).attr('id'),
    })
    .modal('toggle');
  
  $('#headerModal').text(
    'Would like to request a session with ' +            
    $(outer).find('#pro_first_name').text()
  );
});

$(document).on('click', '#modalRequest', function(){
  console.log($("#myModal").data());
});

$(document).on('keyup', '#messageReq', function(e){
  var $modal = $('#myModal')
  // get the data
  var data = $modal.data()
  // assign the text field value to the data
  data.msg = this.value
  // reset the data on the modal element
  $modal.data(data)
})
```

```css
.profileDiv,
#modalRequest {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #bada55;
  float: left;
  margin: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profileDiv" id="myModal">profileDiv</div>
<div id="modalRequest">
  modalRequest
  <input id="messageReq" 
    type="text" 
    name="messageRequest" 
    placeholder="Present yourself" />
</div>
```

Comment: works great and I feel like this is already better than global like you said. I understand it well enough but when I log the object i get the entered data but also `bs.modal: c` and it looks like this is just a reference to where the data came from. Is it ok to just ignore this and move on? (added a `.` in front of `modal` )

Comment: It's working for me in the stacksnippet, are you sure there isn't another error?

Comment: And real quick if you still get this! there is an `input` box inside the modal that I'm trying to add to the object in data. Doing so when the `data.fn` is created doesn't work when the modal is properly closed but when you open it again on any other div you see the message there and its saved and passed into the object of `data.fn`. Why is that?

Comment: Oh the code is working fine, its just when I log it I also get this is what I get `Object {pro_id: "7", bs.modal: c}` and that last inserted object looks like it just details where the `data.fn` came from. was just wondering if that was normal and ok to just kind of ignore?

Comment: The modal plugin probably uses the same method to store some data about it's state. You can just ignore it, and should probably not modify it as it could cause an issue in the modal plugin.

Comment: cool. And if I wanted to add the text from an input box in the modal body to the object in data how would I do that? `<input id="messageReq" type="text" name="messageRequest" placeholder="Present yourself" style="width: 100%;">`

Comment: scratch that last question. I got it with `$("#myModal").data().message = $("#messageReq").val();` inside the modal `click` handler. Thanks for everything muh dude